# Skew-symmetric trilinear form and integration by parts

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

In this paper, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999117304643, the skew-symmetric trilinear form $b^*: H^1(Ω)×H^1(Ω)×H^1(Ω) \to \mathbb R$ is defined as $b^*(u,v,w):=\frac{1}{2}(u. \nabla v,w)-\frac{1}{2}(u. \nabla w,v)$, where $(.,.)$ is the inner product which is defined as $(p,q):=\int_\Omega p(x)q(x)dx$ for $p,q:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ and $p,q\in L^2(\Omega)$, and $(u,v):=\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^{d} u_iv_idx$ for $u,v\in L^2(\Omega)^d$.

I want to prove: $(u.\nabla u,v)=b^*(u,u,v)$, with $\nabla .u=0$ and $v|_{\partial\Omega}=0$ given.

My approach is $(u.\nabla u,v)= \frac{1}{2}(u.\nabla u,v)+\frac{1}{2}(u.\nabla u,v)$.
Or, $(u.\nabla u,v)= \frac{1}{2}(u.\nabla u,v)+\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega (u.\nabla u)vdx$.

I intend to integrate it by parts and get $-\frac{1}{2}(u.\nabla v,u)$ from it. But I don't know how to integrate it by parts, all I know is that the boundary part of the integration is $0$.

Thanks for any help!